# jquery simple modal + asp.net

Tags: jquery, simplemodal

I have a jquery simple modal with a textbox and linkbutton on when the link button click event is fired and I try to get the textbox's value in the code behind it is empty

Any ideas?

Comment: is the linkbutton event client or serverside?

Comment: The Postback causes the Simple Modal to close.
You could iframe it in the Modal

Answer (score 5):

You should make sure that the modal window is appending inside form tag instead of the body tag.

http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/#options

> - appendTo [String:'body']
>
> The jQuery selector to append the elements to. For ASP.NET, use 'form'.

Comment: This is correct, by default most jquery modals (including the UI one) append to the body, so it moves the textbox outside the submitted form.  Because of this, you're not actually posting it's value to the server, using the change in the above answer, it solves this problem.